# iPhone build does not work after migrating project from worklight 6.0 to 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I created a hybrid worklight application having iPhone as the target environment using Worklight Studio 6.0. The application has 1 html file which has HelloWorld written in it.

I then migrated my worklight project to Worklight Studio 6.1. The application builds successfully, but while running the application, the application hangs at the splash screen and does not show the HTML page.

Is there any step that I am missing in the migration activity for iOS?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console, or does it just hang with no errors?

Answer (score 0):

This actually sounds very much likely a recently fixed APAR: PI21872 ON IOS, INSTALLING THE SAME APPLICATION TWICE (WITHOUT unistall) would perform FREEZE AT THE APPLICATION START-UP.

While the APAR title does not match your problem description, it does match the issue that was resolved internally.

- Either take a look at IBM Fix Central and install the latest 6.1.0.1 available there, or
- Open a PMR and request the latest available Worklight 6.1.0.1 iFix

Verify that your issue is then resolved.

Also, since you say you have only "hello world" in your application, you could just create a new project in 6.1 instead?